# Recursive type_alias in sorbet

Tags: ruby, sorbet

How would one declare a type alias that can contain a reference to itself? For example to mark a function returning a JSON-like structure.

Trying:

```
Foo = T.type_alias { T.any(Integer, T::Array[Foo]) }
```

Gives the following error:

> Type alias `Foo` is involved in a cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.5.x, this is not possible, as type aliases don't support cycles.

One option is to lower the typedness of your result, and just make it:

```rb
Foo = T.type_alias { T.any(Integer, T::Array[T.untyped]) }
```

If you really want to have type checking, you can express something like this by wrapping the result in a `T::Struct`. The objects will no longer be as flat as originally, though (see in [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20prop%20%3Acontent%2C%20T.any%28Integer%2C%20T%3A%3AArray%5BFoo%5D%29%0Aend%0A%0AmyFoo%20%3D%20Foo.new%28content%3A%201%29%0Acontent%20%3D%20myFoo.content%0Acase%20content%0Awhen%20Integer%0A%20%20puts%20%22It%20was%20an%20integer!%22%0A%20%20T.reveal_type%28content%29%0Awhen%20Array%0A%20%20puts%20%22It%20was%20a%20Foo!%22%0A%20%20T.reveal_type%28content%29%0Aelse%0A%20%20T.absurd%28content%29%0Aend%0A)):

```rb
class Foo < T::Struct
  prop :content, T.any(Integer, T::Array[Foo])
end

myFoo = Foo.new(content: 1)
content = myFoo.content
case content
when Integer
  puts "It was an integer!"
  T.reveal_type(content)
when Array
  puts "It was a Foo!"
  T.reveal_type(content)
else
  T.absurd(content)
end
```

Edit (2022-02): The documentation on [`type_alias`](https://sorbet.org/docs/type-aliases#what-about-recursive-type-aliases) has been updated to address recursive definitions. It includes an example for JSON-like structures in [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Amodule%20MyJSON%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%20%20sealed!%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams%28json%3A%20T.untyped%29.returns%28MyJSON%29%7D%0A%20%20def%20self.from_untyped%28json%29%0A%20%20%20%20case%20json%0A%20%20%20%20when%20nil%20then%20JSONNull.instance%0A%20%20%20%20when%20String%20then%20JSONString.new%28val%3A%20json%29%0A%20%20%20%20when%20Numeric%20then%20JSONNumber.new%28val%3A%20json%29%0A%20%20%20%20when%20Array%20then%20JSONArray.new%28val%3A%20json.map%20%7B%7Cj%7C%20from_untyped%28j%29%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20when%20Hash%20then%20JSONObject.new%28val%3A%20json.transform_values%20%7B%7Cj%7C%20from_untyped%28j%29%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%20raise%28ArgumentError.new%28%22malformed%20json%22%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20class%20JSONNull%0A%20%20%20%20include%20MyJSON%0A%20%20%20%20include%20Singleton%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20class%20JSONString%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20include%20MyJSON%0A%20%20%20%20prop%20%3Aval%2C%20String%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20class%20JSONNumber%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20include%20MyJSON%0A%20%20%20%20prop%20%3Aval%2C%20Numeric%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20class%20JSONArray%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20include%20MyJSON%0A%20%20%20%20prop%20%3Aval%2C%20T%3A%3AArray%5BMyJSON%5D%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20class%20JSONObject%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20include%20MyJSON%0A%20%20%20%20prop%20%3Aval%2C%20T%3A%3AHash%5BString%2C%20MyJSON%5D%0A%20%20end%0Aend).